# Schedule batch job using cron expression

Tags: schedulebatch, cron

I have a requirement where I need to schedule a  batch job 4 times in a day, at 1 AM EST, 10 AM EST, 3 PM EST, and 8 PM EST. I have scheduled this using a cron expression in Developer Console.

I have prepared the script below, please advise if is this correct.

```
className c = new className();
String sch = '0 0 1,10,15,20 * * *';
system.schedule('Four times in day ', sch, c);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, your string is not correct. You cannot use `*` in both the fourth and sixth positions. Instead, you would need to use a `?`, such as:

```
0 0 1,10,15,20 * * ?
```

Also, please note that your string is only correct if your user account is in EST. If you are in a different time zone, you must calculate what the hours would be in your time zone.